# Prototype for XXX::XXX does not match any in class XXX

Tags: c++

I have written this simple code:

main.h

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H

#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdlib.h>

class Parameters
{
    private:
        std::string _hostname, _channel, _syslogs;
        int _port;
        std::vector<std::string> _list;
    public:
        std::string getHost() {return _hostname;}
        std::string getChan() {return _channel;}
        std::string getSys()  {return _syslogs;}
        std::vector<std::string> getList() {return _list;}
        int getPort() {return _port;}
};

#endif // MAIN_H header guard
```

main.cpp

```
#include "main.h"

using namespace std;

Parameters::Parameters (int argc, char** argv){
    if (argc<2 || argc>4){
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: Invalid count of parameters\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    Parameters parameters(argc,argv);
    return 0;
}
```

But it won't compile. G++ error:

```
g++ -Wall -fexceptions -g -Wextra -Wall  -c
/home/pathtoproject/main.cpp -o obj/Debug/main.o
/home/pathtoproject/main.cpp:13:1: error: prototype for
‘Parameters::Parameters(int, char**)’ does not match any in class
‘Parameters’
```

I am using G++ 4.8 (and CB 13.12 IDE).

Comment: All member functions that you eventually define, including constructors, have to be declared as class members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to supply an implementation of a constructor that you have not declared as part of the class declaration.

You need to add this line to the `public:` section of your class:

```
Parameters (int argc, char** argv);
```

This is the missing prototype about which the compiler is complaining. Adding this prototype will *declare* in the `main.h` the constructor that you are *defining* in your `main.cpp`.

Comment: Ah sure ... i didnt used C++ for a long time.. sorry for stupid question, thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a declaration of the constructor into `Parameters`:

```
class Parameters
{
    private:
        // ...
    public:
        // ...
        Parameters(int argc, char** argv);
};
```

Otherwise, the compiler does not know that the constructor exists in other translation units where only the header is included. Your constructor must be declared `public` section, so that it can be called in `main`.